# Creating a class to store callback functions, is this method okay?

Tags: php, function, object, callback

I have a function, which in basic terms, does the following:
**initiates variables --> `while` loop -> store result in database.**
but, since various parts of my project uses this function, I had to add callback functions for each step, to give myself some flexibility.

My current implementation looks like this:

```
function doStuff(arg1, arg2, $callbacks = array())
{
    //Init vars
    $var1 = ...
    $var2 = ...

    $callbacks['onStart']();//callback..

    //Loop:
    while(....)
    {

       $callbacks['afterCycle']; //callback after each loop.
    }

    //Database storage.
    $this->store($data);

    $callbacks['onEnd'](); //callback...

    }
```

But my current implementation for this function isn't satisfying for me, I think it's not easy to maintain the code, and if I ever wanted to create another similar function(init->loop->storage), I'll be repeating myself, and my code wouldn't be consistent, for example, the current after-loop callback function is called "afterCycle", but for another function, it *could* be called "afterLoop", which will make my code inconsistent and harder to understand.

My current thoughts on this is to create a class that stores these callback function in pre-defined public fields, so the names are unchangeable, also, the function `doStuff` will enforce passing an object of that callback class. I'm not sure yet if this new implementation is any good, that's why I'm asking here.

The new implemenation I have in mind would look like this:

```
function doStuff(arg1, arg2, Callback $callbacks)
{
    //Init vars
    $var1 = ...
    $var2 = ...

    $callbacks->onStart();//callback..

    //Loop:
    while(....)
    {

       $callbacks->afterCycle(); //callback after each loop.
    }

    //Database storage.
    $this->store($data);

   $callbacks->onEnd(); //callback...

    }
```

Comment: Look at the SPL_Observable interface or general information about the Observer Pattern and Pub/Sub.

Comment: I'd suggest you need some kind of event-oriented architecture here, to allow decoupling and flexibility.

Comment: This question might be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [interface](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php)

```
interface ICallBack {
    public function onStart();
    public function afterCycle();
    public function onEnd();
}

//So all the methods in ICallBack must be implemented within CallBack
class CallBack implements ICallBack {
    public function onStart() {
        //blah
    }       

    ...
}


function doStuff(arg1, arg2, ICallback $callback){
   //Init vars
   $var1 = ...
   $var2 = ...

   $callback->onStart();//callback..

   ....
}
```